# Missing argument for parameter 'fact' in call

Tags: swift

One Piece Manager class

```
import Foundation

import UIKit

import GameKit

struct OnePieceManager {

    let fact: String
    let color: UIColor
    let music: String

}

struct OnePiece {
    private let onePieceFacts = [OnePieceManager(fact: "Oda was born in Kumamoto, Japan on January 1, 1975.", color: UIColor(red:1.00, green:0.42, blue:0.00, alpha:1.00), music: "song"),

                                 OnePieceManager(fact: "One Piece is currently the best selling manga in the world, it sold well over 380 million copies and it is not stopping there.", color:  UIColor(red:0.98, green:0.70, blue:0.00, alpha:1.00), music: "song"),

                                 OnePieceManager(fact:   "Even though Luffy is the main character of One Piece, Nami appears on screen before Luffy in the anime making her the first main character to be seen.", color: UIColor(red:0.28, green:0.21, blue:0.42, alpha:1.00), music: "song"),

                                 OnePieceManager(fact: "The only way Luffy will part from his crew is either if he becomes the Pirate King or if he dies.", color: UIColor(red:1.00, green:0.63, blue:0.00, alpha:1.00), music: "song")]

    func randomFact() -> OnePieceManager {

        let randomNumber = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextInt(upperBound: onePieceFacts.count)
        return onePieceFacts[randomNumber]
    }
}
```

Facts view Controller

```
import Foundation

import UIKit

import AVFoundation

class FactsViewController: UIViewController  {

    @IBOutlet weak var onePieceFactlbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var onePieceFactBtn: UIButton!

    let onePieceManager = OnePieceManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }


    @IBAction func onePieceFactBtnDidTouch(_ sender: Any) {


    }
}
```

Comment: Please format the code so it is readable

Comment: You have to write the parameters in the initializer `let onePieceManager = OnePieceManager()`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line

```
let onePieceManager = OnePieceManager()
```

so either `init` like this

```
let onePieceManager = OnePieceManager(fact: "Oda", color: UIColor(red:1.00, green:0.42, blue:0.00, alpha:1.00), music: "song")
```

**OR**

```
var onePieceManager:OnePieceManager?
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike a `class` a `struct` with non-optional members provides a synthesized (called *memberwise*) initializer

```
init(fact: String, color: UIColor, music: String)
```

which is designated. That means you have to use it, it's not possible to use the default initializer `()`.

Declare the variable `onePieceManager` in `FactsViewController` as optional – or if a value is set before using it as implicit unwrapped optional:

```
var onePieceManager : OnePieceManager? // or OnePieceManager!
```